# How can I plot a line on my webgl surface plot?

Tags: javascript, plot, webgl, line, surface

I would like to know how I can plot a line on a webgl surface plot. I currently use SurfacePlot.js based on webgl. I don't know how I can add an other element on this 3D chart. I attach my code with only the surface plotted.

```
 <!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="js/webgl_surface_plot/excanvas.js">   </script><![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src='js/webgl_surface_plot/SurfacePlot.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='js/webgl_surface_plot/ColourGradient.js'>    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/webgl_surface_plot/glMatrix-0.9.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/webgl_surface_plot/webgl-utils.js"></script>

    <script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        #ifdef GL_ES
        precision highp float;
        #endif

        varying vec4 vColor;
        varying vec3 vLightWeighting;

        void main(void)
        {
            gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor.rgb * vLightWeighting, vColor.a);
        }
    </script>

    <script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
        attribute vec3 aVertexNormal;
        attribute vec4 aVertexColor;

        uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
        uniform mat4 uPMatrix;
        uniform mat3 uNMatrix;
        varying vec4 vColor;

        uniform vec3 uAmbientColor;
        uniform vec3 uLightingDirection;
        uniform vec3 uDirectionalColor;
        varying vec3 vLightWeighting;

        void main(void)
        {
            gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);

            vec3 transformedNormal = uNMatrix * aVertexNormal;
            float directionalLightWeighting = max(dot(transformedNormal, uLightingDirection), 0.0);
            vLightWeighting = uAmbientColor + uDirectionalColor * directionalLightWeighting; 

            vColor = aVertexColor;
        }
    </script>

    <script id="axes-shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        precision mediump float;
        varying vec4 vColor;

        void main(void)
        {
            gl_FragColor = vColor;
        }
    </script>

    <script id="axes-shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
        attribute vec4 aVertexColor;
        uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
        uniform mat4 uPMatrix;
        varying vec4 vColor;
        uniform vec3 uAxesColour;

        void main(void)
        {
            gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
            vColor =  vec4(uAxesColour, 1.0);
        } 
    </script>

    <script id="texture-shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        #ifdef GL_ES
        precision highp float;
        #endif

        varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

        uniform sampler2D uSampler;

        void main(void)
        {
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(uSampler, vTextureCoord);
        }
    </script>

    <script id="texture-shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;

        attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;
        varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

        uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
        uniform mat4 uPMatrix;

        void main(void)
        {
            gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
            vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord; 
        }
    </script>

            <script type='text/javascript'>

        var surfacePlot;
        var data, options, basicPlotOptions, glOptions, plot, values2;

        var numRows = 90;
        var numCols = 90;
        var d1 = 0;
        var d2 = 0;
        var xLB = 0;
        var yLB = 0;
        <%= (String) request.getAttribute("varxInterval") %> 
        d1 = xInterval / (numRows-1);
        <%= (String) request.getAttribute("varyInterval")%> 
        d2 = yInterval /(numCols-1);
        <%= (String) request.getAttribute("varxLB")%>
        <%= (String) request.getAttribute("varyLB")%>

        function setUp()
        {


            var tooltipStrings = new Array();
            values2 = new Array();


            data = {nRows: numRows, nCols: numCols, formattedValues: values2};


            //int numRows = (int) (Integer) request.getAttribute("numRows");
            //int x = (Integer) request.getAttribute("x");
            //int y = (Integer) request.getAttribute("y");
            //Output output = (Output) system.getOutDefs((Integer) request.getAttribute("z")).getOut();
            //double d1 = ((Double) request.getAttribute("xInterval")) / (numRows-1);

            var idx = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) 
            {
                values2[i] = new Array();
                for (var j = 0; j < numCols; j++)
                {

                    var xval = xLB + ((i * d1 * 1000) / 1000);
                    var yval = yLB + ( (j * d2 * 1000) / 1000);
                    values2[i][j] = datas3d[i][j];  

                    tooltipStrings[idx] = "x:" + xval + ", y:" + yval + " = " + values2[i][j];

                    idx++;
                }
            }

            surfacePlot = new SurfacePlot(document.getElementById("surfacePlotDiv"));

            // Don't fill polygons in IE < v9. It's too slow.
            var fillPly = true;

            // Define a colour gradient.
            var colour1 = {red:0, green:0, blue:255};
            var colour2 = {red:0, green:255, blue:255};
            var colour3 = {red:0, green:255, blue:0};
            var colour4 = {red:255, green:255, blue:0};
            var colour5 = {red:255, green:0, blue:0};
            var black = {red:0, green:0, blue:0};
            var grey = {red:200, green:200, blue:200};
            <%
            if (system.getPrefs().blackAndWhite) {
                out.println("var colours = [black, grey];");
            } else {
                out.println("var colours = [colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4, colour5];");
            }
            %>

            // Axis labels.
            var xAxisHeader = "<%= (String) request.getAttribute("xAxisHeader") %>";
            var yAxisHeader = "<%= (String) request.getAttribute("yAxisHeader") %>";

            var renderDataPoints = false;
            var background = '#ffffff';
            var axisForeColour = '#000000';
            var hideFloorPolygons = false;
            var chartOrigin = {x: 450, y:350};

            // Options for the basic canvas pliot.
            basicPlotOptions = {fillPolygons: fillPly, tooltips: tooltipStrings, renderPoints: renderDataPoints };

            // Options for the webGL plot.
            var xLabels = <%= (String) request.getAttribute("xLabels") %>;
            var yLabels = <%= (String) request.getAttribute("yLabels") %>;
            var zLabels = [0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1]; // These labels ar eused when autoCalcZScale is false;
            glOptions = {xLabels: xLabels, yLabels: yLabels, zLabels: zLabels, chkControlId: "allowWebGL", autoCalcZScale: true, animate: false};

            // Options common to both types of plot.
            options = {xPos: 0, yPos: 0, width: 700, height: 500, colourGradient: colours, 
            xTitle: xAxisHeader, yTitle: yAxisHeader, zTitle: "Certainty",
            backColour: background, axisTextColour: axisForeColour,          hideFlatMinPolygons: hideFloorPolygons, origin: chartOrigin};

            surfacePlot.draw(data, options, basicPlotOptions, glOptions);


        }
```

I need to add this line above the surface in the axes Z=1.

Comment: Take a look at the this.createAxes function at line 739 in SurfacePlot.js. This is the code that renders the axis lines. You can use this as an example of drawing lines on the surface.